# Acknowledgement sent in socket communication not fast enough

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a socket listener to a device that requires an acknowledgement before it sends the next set of data to the server. I'm able to send the acknowledgement but by the time a new connection is created and as a result I lose data. I have pasted my code below.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        servSoc = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        File file = new File("logs.txt");
        // creates the file

        Socket server = null;
        //FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port "
                        + servSoc.getLocalPort() + "...");
                server = servSoc.accept();
                System.out.println("Just connected to "
                        + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream());
                //InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out =
                        new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                new Thread(new LogWriter(in, out)).start();

                // Writes the content to the file

                if (servSoc.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("Connection closed....");
                    servSoc.close();
                }
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                s.printStackTrace();
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SenselSocketListner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int port = 8294;
    Thread t = new SenselSocketListner(port);
    t.start();
}
```

My log writer thread is given below.

```
public class LogWriter implements Runnable {

InputStreamReader in;
DataOutputStream out;

public LogWriter(InputStreamReader in, DataOutputStream out) {
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        File file = new File("logs.txt");
        // creates the file
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Creating File");
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        String inputLine = null;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(in);


        System.out.println("Writing data....");
        while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println("Test");
            System.out.println("Sending Acknowledgement....");
            out.writeUTF("Upload successful");
            out.writeUTF("Ok");
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, true);
            BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            fbw.write(inputLine);
            fbw.newLine();
            fbw.flush();
            fbw.close();
        }
        //DataOutputStream out =
        //new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        //out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
        //server.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogWriter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Person concerned with the device suggested that I might not be sending the acknowledgement fast enough. Please help me to find a way to speed this up, I have notices a delay after the statement "System.out.println("Writing data....");" in the log writer.

Comment: Please state clearly whether the "device" is programmed in Java and whether the reader over there uses readUTF. It would be a bad surprise if the protocol does not account for the specific way of writing and reading strings.

Comment: The device that is in use is a third party device so I dont't know if it is programmed in java or not, as suggested by EJP I tried using writechars instead of writeUTF, but it did not work. I also tried writing the data to the device as soon as the input stream is received but still no success.

Comment: What makes you use a DataOutputStream then, of all things? What is the definition of the protocol, i.e., what does the "3rd party device" really expect? Does it expect it after sending a single line?

Comment: As in the case of DataOutputStream I just saw a sample code on-line an used it to create my socket and I was building the rest from there. The device expects "Upload successful" and "Ok" and it expects to receive it after receiving every single line.

Comment: Well, you can't assume that code written for one scenario works for all other scenarios. If the device expects a couple of lines of text, you better send a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the device really understand the result of `writeUTF()`? Unless it is implemented in Java it is highly unlikely. You should surely just be writing the bytes or chars of the message directly.

Other notes:

- Creating a new log file per line is wasting time. Open the file before the read loop, and close it afterw the loop.
- Closing the server socket if it's already closed doesn't make sense.
- You should close the accepted socket when `readLine()` returns null, in the reading thread.

Comment: @laune The contract of this method clearly states that a 16-bit length word is written to the stream, followed by a modified UTF-encoding of the actual characters. The only method that can read this data is `readUTF()`, which is only found in Java, and not to be expected on hardware devices.  There is nothing strange about the question, but there is something very, very, very strange about your highly selective reading of the documentation.

Comment: @laune I can ony suggest you read my answer again. Unless the device uses Java, it is extremely unlikely that it will even have an implementation of `readUTF()`, and therefore unlikely that it can read the responses he's writing with `writeUTF()` correctly: which would explain the problem he is having. Hence the question. It's far more likely that the device is reading lines, for example. You don't have any evidence that this isn't the source of the problem, and it is both selective and very very strange to completely overlook the unique nature of `read/writeUTF()` when evaluating this answer.

Comment: I say, this talk of "device" has confused me no end. Usual parlance is "client software". I have removed all traces of my failure to understand "device". That someone could fail to implement the protocol in a symmetric way never entered my mind, but all the other strange constructs should have alerted me. - Your "other notes" coincide with what I wrote earlier.

Comment: @laune Well as he was using 'device' rather than 'client software', it is difficult to see how you got confused. *One* of my 'other notes' also appears in your post. Is it your personal property? Copyright? Patent pending?

Answer (score -1):

The while loop in run in LogWriter traps your app until the socket is closed. If you need to converse on a socket, you'll have to know what to expect - as defined by a protocol. If it is one line, just read one line. If it is a text file, you'll have to devise a protocol that informs you about the number of bytes to expect.

Also, logging should be done on a single open log file, without close after each line.